# SQL script population table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sequence, sql-insert

I'm here with a question: How can I insert some row in a table automatically?

I did this:

```sql
INSERT INTO ASSEMBLY (Machine_ID, Assembly_model, Assembly_text, Serial_number)
VALUES (1, '592-000', 'Model in text form', 148)
```

where the `Machine_ID` is the primary key.

How could I add rows in the table, automatically incrementing the `Machine_ID` and the `Serial_number` columns?

I would like to add 300 lines without changing the data manually; I'm using SQL Server Management Studio for working with the database.

Comment: Are you able to ALTER the 'assembly' table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a series of numbers with  `row_number()` against a large table, and then use that information in an `insert ... select` statement:

```
with cte as (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn from bigtable)
insert into assembly (machine_id, assembly_model, assembly_text, serial_number)
select rn, '592-000', 'Model in text form', 147 + rn
from cte
where rn <= 300
```

You can replace `bigtable` in the CTE with any existing table that has at least 300 rows (for example, you could use [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

If there are records in the table already, then:

```
with cte as (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn from bigtable)
insert into assembly (machine_id, assembly_model, assembly_text, serial_number)
select a.max_machine_id + c.rn, '592-000', 'Model in text form', 147 + c.rn
from cte c
cross join (select max(machine_id) max_machine_id from assembly) a
where rn <= 300
```

This adds 300 records to the table, starting from from the greatest available `machine_id`. If, on the other hand, you want to fill the table up until 300 records, then just change the `where` clause:

```
where c.rn + a.machine_id <= 300
```

Comment: I replace bigtable with sys.columns, I encountered an error as I already have 4 records in this table, which I would like to keep. How do I change your code to put me from line 5 to line 300?

Comment: You could always add something like this in the `WHERE` clause `AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM assembly x WHERE x.machine_id = rn)`